# How can I know if an element is a direct child of the body using jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, traversal

I want to perform some action on elements that are not direct child of the body. How can I check a particular element to know whether its partent is the body.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can test the tag name this way :

```
jQuery('#urDivId').parent().is('body')
```

Answer (score 3):

The `>` denotes a direct child. `$('body > *')` gives you all children of the body tag, so you could always invert that with a `:not( )`: `$('*:not(body > *)')`; however that might be pretty slow.

`filter( )` would also work for you and may be faster: `$('body *').filter(function(){ return $(this).parent('body') });`

Either of the above should give you a complete set of all elements that are not children of the body tag.

Note that there could potentially be a huge number of elements selected here; you will want to make your selectors as specific as possible for performance and you should probably avoid wildcards, which I used for the sake of the examples above.

Answer (score 1):

simply you can use the parent function  `jquery('#yourElement').parent();`  if it gives you body tag than you can find that its direct child of body.

Comment: It's `jQuery`, with a capital `Q`. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( $(this).parent()[0].nodeName.toLowerCase() == "body" ) 
{
// do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of good answers.  If you are interested in chaining, here is yet another possibility that uses [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) and the [:not() selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).

```
var $possible_targets = [...]; // all the elements you want to check
function do_something_to_target() { 
    [...]; // insert blinking text code here! 
}

$possible_targets.parent(':not(body)').each(do_something_to_target);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make good use of jQuery selectors:

```
if($('body > #divId').length > 0) {
    // your div is a direct child of body
}
```